# azure devops CI pipeline error: [error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found

Tags: git, asp.net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I'm trying to build the .net core 3.1 application using Azure DevOps CI pipeline by integrating the other Git repo and provided the service connection to the Git repo. The screen shots shows the configurations I have choosen. The Git service connection url is `https://abc/efg/hij/klm/_git/branch1`

The project file path : `https://abc/efg/hij/klm/_git/branch1/solution1Name/projectname/projectname.csproj`

and solution file path:
`https://abc/efg/hij/klm/_git/branch1/solution1Name/solutionName.sln`

But
I ended up getting the below error
`##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found`.

I have multiple solutions under `branch1` and one among them is `solution1Name`.  Let me know if you need any more help. I'm stuck from 1 day bugging on this.

Build steps attached below

[pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxrnu.png)

[git sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjSXh.png)

[Agent Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArIxT.png)
[Nuget restore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCv1K.png)

[VsBuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onOXI.png)

Comment: The error means that the build-task can't find any *.sln in you repository. So what you want to know? Do you have any *.sln files in your repository?

Comment: Yes I do have .sln in my Git repo. My git repo is not the Azure Git repo but its Other Git. I have attached the screenshots

Comment: If you have a single solution to build, you can avoid to use wildcards and select one single solution by clicking the "three-dot" button. In that way it works?

Comment: Take a look at this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoFAR_6KDFo

Comment: @ Nishān Wickramarathna: This youtube video is for CI Pipeline for 'Azure Git' repo but I have 'Other Git' repo

Comment: @Lorenzo Isidori: What is "three-dot" button ?

Comment: The `VSBuild` step has the solution property to set. So there is the label "Solution", next to right there is a textbox where you can type and next to right there is a button who let you pick up a .sln from your repository.